# Newer Android versions corrupting sqlite database on copy?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm making updates to a client's sqlite database that's used in their mobile apps. For some reason with this latest update I'm working on, on newer Android devices it says the database is corrupted when it tries doing some queries. (I say some because it loads the initial categories from the db but when I try to view the subcategories, or do a product search, this is when it breaks.)

I'm getting these errors when I run it on a Pixel phone emmulated:

> E/ProductDatabase: database created
>   E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 61982 of [8201f4e1c5]
>   E/SQLiteLog: (11) statement aborts at 17: [SELECT cast(Name as text) as Name FROM ProductType ORDER BY SortOrder] database disk image is malformed
>   E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/user/0/com.client.client/databases/products.sqlite
>   E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: deleting the database file: /data/user/0/com.client.client/databases/products.sqlite

But,

- It works on older Android devices (like Nexus 5)
- It works on ios
- When I do an integrity check it's fine.
- It opens fine in multiple sqlite viewers.

So I believe it very much to not be an issue with a corrupted sqlite file. I read something on a forum yesterday about how it could be corrupting on copy or it could be a permissions issue with newer Android Version, but I can't for the life of me, find this page again or any other pages mentioning this.

What could be going on? I've cleaned and rebuilt the project and uninstalled the app from the emulated phone countless times, played around with the DB version in Java, tried deleting the DB onUpgrade and nothing works. I'm not an Android developer, just a frustrated, front-end developer trying to make some simple database updates...

Comment: Does the app ever access the database file directly (e.g., when copying it from somewhere)?

Comment: @CL. I'm not sure what that means? Both onCreate and onUpgrade copy the db in the standard way. https://prnt.sc/i8rwoo It's not going into the catch block either.

Comment: That "standard" way is dangerous; you probably forgot to close all connections to the DB. (See [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_file_overwrite_by_a_rogue_thread_or_process).) You should have used [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: @CL. In my screenshot I'm clearly closing the connection. Anyway, I switched to SQLiteAssetHelper and it's better. Working at least, but buggy.

Comment: @pinksharpii do you have any solution on this?

Comment: The same thing works for me in a Sample app, but when I integrate it to my main app, even the most basic Select query hangs saying the database is corrupted!